# Twitter widget is not loading on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have following code snippet which on working fine in localhost, fiddle but just not working on my client site which is confidential can't share. Just account is different.

Problem is when site loads first time nothing shows up an empty iframe with no error on console.

But if I refresh the page again all of sudden twitter widget start working again. I am not sure whats going wrong with this.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know what else I can share here that can help you figure out the issue.

Thanks

```
<div class="left-twwiter-section"> <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/AamirShahzd" data-widget-id="629643369577234432">Tweets by @AamirShahzd</a>

    <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You're likely dealing with a race condition, by the sound of it. Loading resources from cache is a lot faster than loading from a server.

Comment: @user2867288 will you please elaborate?

Comment: Race conditions can happen when there's any sort of asynchronous task, such as waiting for the dom to load or using setTimeout, that is reliant on another asynchronous task to complete first. Usually the inconsistent behavior you're describing happens because of a race condition.

Comment: Yes I suspect that there are other async calls on the page as well. Will share if found some issue.